# Simple way to count all where has 0 relations with specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some trouble writing well performing query. Now I have two tables:

Cars:

```
id   brand   model_name
1    'Audi'  'A4'
2    'Audi'  'A4'
3    'Audi'  'A4'
4    'Audi'  'A6'
5    'Audi'  'A7'
```

Buyers:

```
id   cars_id  name     activly_looking
1    2        'Brad'   'no'
2    2        'Kim'    'maybe'
3    4        'Sofia'  'yes'
4    4        'Tim'    'no'
5    5        'Tina'   'yes'
```

Now I need to select the count of cars that: HAS buyers but does NOT have any buyers who are `activly_looking = 'yes'`

The query should in this example return the count of `1`, since only car with id `2` fulfill the criteria.

BTW. this will be done as a onetime query to debug an issue, but on a quite huge table (Millions of rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using conditional aggregation to filter all cars that have `actively_looking = yes` buyers.

The inner join ensures that the car has at least 1 buyer and the having clause ensures that none of the buyers are actively looking.

```
select count(*) from (
    select c.id from cars c
    join buyers b on b.cars_id = c.id
    group by c.id
    having count(case when b.activly_looking = 'yes' then 1 end) = 0
) t1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` and `not exists` to check your conditions and then just do an aggregation query:

```
select count(*)
from cars c
where exists (select 1 from buyers b where b.cars_id = c.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from buyers b where b.cars_id = c.id and b.acively_looking = 'yes')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a `left outer join buyers` rather than doing subqueries for each?

Comment: @NielsKristian . . . Better in what sense?  If you don't like `exists` then it would be better I suppose.  If you used joins, you would need `count(distinct)` in the outer query.  This method should perform better with the right index.

Comment: @NielsKristian `EXISTS` queries generally perform better. `LEFT JOIN` vs `LEFT SEMI JOIN`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 select count(b.cars_id) from
    from cars c
    left join buyers b on b.cars_id = c.id
    where b.activly_looking = 'yes'
    group by c.id
```